# Get object or all in django query_set

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'))
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('user'))
    ...
```

and i want:

if the user authenticated:

**return the user products**

else if user did not authenticate:

**return all products**

in linq C# we can solve this problem with:

```
Product.Where(!request.user.is_authenticated() || user.id == request.user.id)
```

i know that in python can solve it with `if else`:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return Product.objects.filter(user=request.user)

else:
    return Product.objects.all()
```

**Question**: is there a solution like the C# linq?

Answer (score 0):

There is, but it's pretty ugly:

```
return Product.objects.filter(**{'user': request.user}
    if request.user.is_authenticated else **{})
```

I think the if/else solution is better.